# Grafana - Failed to add datasource

Tags: sql, datasource, monitoring, grafana, influxdb

I was add datasource to Grafana. I haven't made any changes. But right now, I can't add datasource. A have error: "Failed to add datasource".

Error image:

[image]

If there is missing information, I can elaborate.

Comment: What does the logs indicate ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. When i add datasource, i get error in log file.

Log: t=2021-08-12T12:33:03+0300 lvl=eror msg="Failed to add datasource" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="UNIQUE constraint failed: data_source.org_id, data_source.uid" remote_addr=***

Comment: You can connect to the db via cli/ui and remove the constraint directly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your support. I connected to the db (..\grafana\data\grafana.db) via ui, I saw  zero in the uid column of the most recently added data source. Normally it should have written id number in uid column. After updating the id column from the database, I can add a record. But on the second insert I get the same error. Why doesn't grafana write single uid?

Comment: Detection: Grafana added zero value in unique coloumn of database. When adding new datasource Grafana add zero value same column of database. But it can't add because it is a unique column. It is get error.